# How can I download a complete page including webfonts such as Fontawesome?

Tags: css, wget

I want to build an HTTPS proxy that can deliver a HTTP site as HTTPS so that it can be used in an iframe without mixed content errors.

Tools such as wget and Firefox have the capability to download complete pages but they miss font files linked with url() in CSS files. Example:

```
wget -k -p http://fontawesome.io/
```

If you now open the offline copy of that site all font icons are broken because wget failed to download the font files and replace the url() directives in CSS.

Is there a tool that also includes font files in CSS for offline site copies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So due to robots.txt restrictions (which wget respects) not all files were downloaded.

This is working now, telling wget to ignore robots.txt:

```
wget -k -p --adjust-extension -e robots=off http://fontawesome.io/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one with same parameters :

```
wget -r –no-parent http://fontawesome.io/
```

or

```
wget -r –no-parent http://www.naveedramzan.com
```

Comment: I don't want the -r option because I only want to download a single page. The --no-parent option also doesn't help me, the page is still broken in the offline version not showing the font.